# cannot assign to conditional expression

Tags: python

```
if i+1 < stages[i]: tried[i] = (tried[i] + 1) if tried[i] != None else tried[i] = 0
```

> if i+1 < stages[i]: tried[i] = (tried[i] + 1) if tried[i] != None
>   else tried[i] = 0
>                                     ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression

I got an error of `cannot assign to conditional expression`. Not sure which part I did wrong.

Comment: Why not a "normal" `if else` statement instead?

Comment: `true_expr if cond else false_expr` only works with _expressions_. Assignment is not an expression; use the full `if` statement, or extract the assignment outside the `if` expression.

Comment: ....can you try to format it properly...as there is probably the issue

Comment: @mikuszefski: It _is_ formatted properly. He's just doing something that doesn't work.

Comment: @Amadan well obviously somehing is wrong, but fair enough, if the last statement just goes to `0` as in the answers below, it would work. Nevertheless, a line break after the first `if` statement would, e.g., help. The readability of mixing `if` and conditional is definitively not the best.

Comment: @mikuszefski: I agree the readability is horrible, but the lack of line break is not the direct cause of the error. And there are valid reasons for wanting a one-liner (though Python is a horrible choice if that's what you're going for).

Comment: @Amadan :) agreed.

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
if i+1 < stages[i]: tried[i] = (tried[i] + 1) if tried[i] != None else 0
```

without the last `triend[i] = 0`, just `0` (also `triend` would be probably wrong anyway).

Comment: Also, as an extra piece of advice: if you use `-1` as initialization for `tried[i]`, this could become a single `if`: `tried[i] = (tried[i] + 1) if i + 1 < stages[i] else -1`. Moreover, if you can initialize `tried[i]` to `-1` beforehand, you could simply write: `tried[i] += int(i + 1 < stages[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

The overall structure you're looking for, since you are trying to accomplish an assignment with multiple conditional expressions, is this:
*variable* = *expression* *condition* else *expression* *condition* ... else *expression*. You can even use parentheses to remind yourself of how it will be parsed: *variable* = (*expression* *condition* else *expression* *condition* ... else *expression*). The total conditional expression must end with "else".

For instance, I have the following code:

```
x = 5
if x == 1:
    a = '1'
elif x == 2:
    a = '2'
else:
    a = '3'
print(a)
```

Using a conditional expression, it becomes:

```
x = 5
a = '1' if x == 1 else '2' if x == 2 else '3'
print(a)
```

I'm not sure what your assignment and conditional expressions

```
if i+1 < stages[i]: tried[i] = (tried[i] + 1) if tried[i] != None else tried[i] = 0
```

would look like when expanded, as some information is missing:

```
missing_expression = '?'
if i+1 < stages[i]:
    tried[i] = (tried[i] + 1)
elif tried[i] != None:
    tried[i] = missing_expression
else:
    tried[i] = 0
```

When the missing expression is supplied, your conditional expression should look like:

```
tried[i] = (tried[i] + 1) if i+1 < stages[i] else missing_expression if tried[i] != None else 0
```